# No comprendo en qué fallo en este ejercicio de introducción a POO en Java

Tags: java

Estoy aprendiendo Java y estoy haciendo un sencillo ejercicio de introducción a POO. Me da error pero no soy capaz de comprender en dónde estoy fallando, uso Netbeans como IDE. Aquí el código de la clase:

```
public class Empleado {

// Decimos qué atributos tendrá nuestra clase
private String nombre;
private String apellido;
private int edad;
private double sueldo;

// Utilizamos los constructores para inicializar dichos atributos
public Empleado(String nombre, String apellido, int edad, double sueldo) {

    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellido = apellido;
    this.edad = edad;
    this.sueldo = sueldo;

}

//Le meto get y set para poder hacer cosas con dichos atributos
public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre() {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getApellido() {
    return apellido;
}

public void setApellido() {
    this.apellido = apellido;
}

public int getEdad() {
    return edad;
}

public void setEdad() {
    this.edad = edad;
}

public double getSueldo() {
    return sueldo;
}

public void setSueldo() {
    this.sueldo = sueldo;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 */
@Override
public String toString () {
    String texto = "El empleado se llama " + nombre + " " + apellido + " y tiene " + edad + " años y cobra un sueldo de " + sueldo + " euros"; 
    return texto;
}
}
```

Y aquí el código del método main:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Empleado trabajador1 = new Empleado ("Pablo", "Fernández", 27, 1050);
    Empleado trabajador2 = new Empleado ("César", "Romero", 26, 1300);

    System.out.println(trabajador1.toString());
    System.out.println(trabajador2.toString());

    trabajador1.setNombre("Lucía");
    trabajador2.setEdad(23);
```

Me da error en los setters y no me deja ejecutar, me dice que

> "method setNombre in class empleado cannot be applied to given types;
>   required: no arguments; found: String; reason: actual and formal
>   argument lists differ in lenght"

Sin embargo, por más que busco en Internet, no doy con el error, ya que a nivel sintáctico creo que lo estoy haciendo bien. ¿Alguna idea? Gracias.

Comment: El problema es que setNombre está definido como que no recibe ningún parámetro y tu le estás pasando un string. Cambia setNombre() por setNombre(String nombre) en la clase Empleado. Lo mismo con setApellido, setEdad y setSueldo. Tienes que decir que van a recibir un String o entero o lo que sea

Comment: El problema es un error de novato, pero la pregunta tiene todos los elementos para que podamos ayudarte, buen trabajo en esa parte!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Los *setters* no están recibiendo ningún parámetro:

```
void setNombre() {
    this.nombre=nombre;
}
```

Deberían ser todos algo como

```
void setNombre(String n) {
    this.nombre=n;
}
```

El código compila en esas clases porque `this.` es opcional, realmente tus setters son equivalentes a

```
void setNombre() {
    this.nombre=this.nombre; //realmente no hace nada
}
```

Consejo de veterano: si usas Eclipse, escribe las clases así:

```
public class Empleado {

    // Decimos qué atributos tendrá nuestra clase
    private String nombre;
    private String apellido;
    private int edad;
    private double sueldo;
}
```

Y entonces pulsa <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Mays</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>. En el menú que aparezca elige *Generate Setters and Getters*

Comment: Por ampliar, en IntelliJ tambien existe esa opción. Botón derecho/Generate../Getters and Setters

Comment: Creo que estamos olvidando un concepto importante. Las funciones (que eso es un setter para Java) que reciben parametros, deben tener declarado el parametro en la definicion de la misma. El error no es el setter en si, si no que no se haya comprendido como es una funcion, como se le pasan parametros y como los recibe.

Comment: @gbianchi la respuesta de pablo creo que explica eso en la primera parte correctamente

Comment: Si si. Me referia a generalizar al setter como una funcion. Porque si OP no lo entendio para un setter, menos lo entendio para una función.

Comment: Solo por aportar a lo comentado de la generación de Getters y Setters en NetBeans existe exactamente la misma opción que comenta Pikoh sobre IntelliJ.

Answer (score 2):

Excelente la respuesta de Pablo Lozano, además quisiera agregar que puedes utilizar la librería para Lombok. Que te genera los setters y getters de manera automática con simples anotaciones.

un ejemplo :

```
import lombok.Getter; 
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter @Setter
public class Persona {

   private String nombre;
   private String apellido;
   private Integer edad;
}
```

Con esto la librería te genera automáticamente tus setters y getters. No olvides de agregar la librería a tu proyecto o como dependencia de maven(que te lo recomiendo que utilices).

Te dejo este [enlace](http://acodigo.blogspot.com/2016/12/reducir-codigo-con-lombok.html) que te puede ser de ayuda con esta librería.

Espero que te sea útil.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando defines una clase estás encapsulando información.

en este caso defines atributos privados (que son inaccesibles, "en teoría", desde fuera de la clase) //cuando domines más puedes mirar lo que es reflection para entender mi "en teoria".

```
MiClase unaInstancia = new MiClase();
unaInstancia.atributoPrivado = 1; // esto daría error
```

la idea de la orientación a objetos es que cada objeto te indique la forma en que puedes interactuar con este.

En tu caso particular defines un setter al que no le pasas información para actualizar. Ten en cuenta que si haces this.variable = parametro es equivalente a hacer el atributo privado público.